# Can we use Boto to deploy Yaml templates?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I am using boto to deploy json templates in AWS. My question is Can i use the same boto library to deploy Templates in Yaml as well.When i tried i got the error no json could be decoded.

If there is a way then please share an example
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you are referring to CloudFormation templates. Make sure that you have up to date boto3 and botocore. The boto3 library does appear to support YAML CloudFormation templates (see comments for http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.validate_template).

Answer (score 0):

We just need to use Yaml decoder in place of json decoder as follows :-

with open(template_path) as yaml_data:
 template = yaml.load(yaml_data)
 template_body = yaml.dump(template)

Don`t forget to import Yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a YAML file directly from Boto3:

```
try:
    with open(template_file_location, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read() 
except OSError as e:
  # error handling in case error reading file
...
boto3_client.validate_template(TemplateBody=content)
```